# Permission denied for creating a search index GAE Geoespacial Query

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, geospatial, google-cloud-datastore

I have include the Geoespacial Query to check if a GeoPt is inside a Circle and I have created a index for it.
When I try to deploy it to GAE, I'm getting the following error:

```
Creating an index failed for entity_type: "MyEntity" ancestor: falseProperty {  name: "name"}Property {  name: "location"  mode: 3}: Permission denied for creating a search index
```

this is the code that I'm Executing

```
        GeoPt center = new GeoPt((float) pLatitude, (float) pLongitude);
        double radius = pDistanceKM*1000;
        Query.Filter f = new StContainsFilter("location", new Circle(center, radius));
        items =  ofy().load().type(MyEntity.class).filter(f).filter("name", tmpName).list();
```

I have created an index according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/geosearch):

This is my index:

```
    <datastore-index kind="MyEntity"  source="manual">
    <property name="name" />
    <property name="location" mode="geospatial"/>
</datastore-index>
```

Does anyone have any idea of what it could be this permission?

Using Java and Android Studio.

Ps: When I try to execute the code, the Logging in the GAE suggest me an index identical as my index

```
com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backend method com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreNeedIndexException: no matching index found. The suggested index for this query is:
<datastore-index kind="MyEntity"  source="manual">
    <property name="name" />
    <property name="location" mode="geospatial"/>
</datastore-index>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geospatial search for Datastore is an [Alpha release](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/geosearch) which has reached capacity for now. Looking at the error, it looks like you aren't part of the Alpha program.

Stay tuned for the Beta which will be open to everyone!

Comment: Is there any date to the Beta release?

Comment: There isn't any date available yet for the beta release.

Comment: @Zeehad Is there any chance for me to get an invitation before the beta release? I'm developing an app which main focus is nearby places. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: do you have any information about when the beta release will start?

Comment: Since this is in alpha now for a very very long time. Will there ever be a beta released? Any information?